# Why label isn't inside the layout?

Tags: python, user-interface, layout, kivy

I'm trying to make some kind of label a bit transparent with text inside it. The problem is that text is not inside the layout and I don't know why.

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Label, Button
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle,Color

class Visor(App):

def build(self):
    Window.size=(400,600)
    print(Window.size)

    r = RelativeLayout()
    r.size = (400, 550)
    with r.canvas:
        Color(0.6, 0.6, .1, 0.8)
        bg_rect =  Rectangle(pos=(0,0), size=(400, 550))

    r2 = FloatLayout()
    r2.size=(100,150)
    with r2.canvas:
        Color(.9, 0.1, 0.6, 0.8)
        bg_rect = Rectangle(pos=(0, 0), size=(200,150))

    r2.pos=(50,70)
    r.add_widget(r2)
    r2.add_widget(Label(text="Detective Comics Vol.1 #878"))
    return r

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Visor().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to use `size_hint` when you are using any layout, and then use proportional coordinates from 0 to 1 (0% to %100). However, if you want to honor `size`, you should deactivate `size_hint` by setting it to `(None, None)`:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Label, Button
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle,Color

class Visor(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.size=(400,600)
        print(Window.size)

        r = RelativeLayout()
        r.size_hint = (None, None) 
        r.size = (400, 550)
        with r.canvas:
            Color(0.6, 0.6, .1, 0.8)
            bg_rect =  Rectangle(pos=(0,0), size=(400, 550))

        r2 = FloatLayout()
        r2.size_hint = (None, None) 
        r2.size=(100,150)
        with r2.canvas:
            Color(.9, 0.1, 0.6, 0.8)
            bg_rect = Rectangle(pos=(0, 0), size=(200,150))

        r2.pos=(50,70)
        r.add_widget(r2)
        r2.add_widget(Label(text="Detective Comics Vol.1 #878"))
        return r

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Visor().run()
```

Moreover, you should be using the Kivy language for this, it is way easier and it can easily bind properties internally.

---

Adding this code to the head of your file can help you spotting layout problems:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string('''
<Widget>:
    canvas.after:
        Line:
            rectangle: self.x+1,self.y+1,self.width-1,self.height-1
            dash_offset: 5
            dash_length: 3
''')
```

For an explanation and other tricks, [go here](http://robertour.com/2013/10/02/easy-way-debugging-kivy-interfaces/)

Comment: Thanks. i see my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Kivy widgets have a property `size_hint` which resizes the widgets depending on the parents size. This is by default set to `(1,1)`, so whenever the parent resizes, the child resizes.

When you set the sizes of the rectangles, these are given by absolute values, which do not resize at all. This means that the colored rectangles are not the "real" size of the layouts.

At least for me when the application starts, the window immediately resizes, and with that the root window (`r`). Then all child widgets resize to 100% of the window size, but the colored rectangles do not resize.

If you set the `size_hint` of the label to `None, None` the resizing will not take place and it should display as you wanted.

Maybe a better way would be to define the rectangles, etc. in a kv language file. I.e.

```
RelativeLayout:
    Label:
        text: "Detective Comics Vol.1 #878"
    canvas:
        Color(0.8, 0.8, .1, 0.8)
        Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
...
```

that way whenever the position or the size of the relative layout changes, the rectangle will get updated.